# Ms ACCESS and SQL: round to two decimals through query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I use queries to calculate all kinds of supplier information (average lead time, total spend for that supplier, average price, etc.). All output is shown in listboxes in forms in Ms ACCESS.

Example of a calculated number:

[image]

How do I format the output of these queries to be rounded to two decimals? I've been playing around with the listbox settings but cannot find it there. I believe I will have to do it in the query itself, but I'm not sure how.

Query code for the above number:

```
SELECT Avg([Item Master].PlannedLeadTime) AS AverageLeadTime
FROM [Item Master]
WHERE ((([Item Master].DateStamp)>=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List2] And ([Item Master].DateStamp)<=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List3]) AND (([Item Master].SupplierName)=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List1]));
```

Note: List1 is a listbox where the user can select a certain supplier (for which the calculations are performed) and list2 and list3 are dates the user can select (as to determine a date range for the calculations).

Comment: Note that `SELECT Round(17.065, 2)` returns 17.06.  Would that be a concern for you?

Comment: No, that is absolutely fine.

Comment: None of the examples here nor links demonstrate how to round up - as your title requests.

Comment: @Gustav fixed title..

Comment: OK, thanks. Also, please note that _Round_ is quite buggy, so if accuracy has any importance, study this link: [Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://rdsrc.us/6r9K3y) for functions that predictably will round any value of any numeric data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access SQL has a rich function set one of which is the `round` function.

Example:

```
SELECT Round(Avg([Item Master].PlannedLeadTime),2) AS AverageLeadTime
FROM [Item Master]
WHERE (...)
```

Further information:
http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/round.php

Answer (score 1):

**Use ROUND() Function:**

The ROUND() function is used to round a numeric field to the number of decimals specified.

**SQL ROUND() Syntax:**

```
SELECT ROUND(column_name,decimals) FROM table_name;

|Parameter    |Description
________________________________________________    
|column_name  |Required. The field to round.
|decimals     |Required. Specifies the number of decimals to be returned.
```

So, Your required query will be:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG([Item Master].PlannedLeadTime),2) AS AverageLeadTime
FROM [Item Master]
WHERE ((([Item Master].DateStamp)>=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List2]
      And ([Item Master].DateStamp)<=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List3])                   AND (([Item Master].SupplierName)=[Forms]![History Supplier Tool]![List1]));
```